# How to create Crystal reports "on fly"?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Problem: SQL query is generated after user input and number of columns can vary greatly.
In program I dynamically create and fill data set, but how can I create dynamic report which uses such customized data source?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've asked same question (more or less) on another site.
I was satisfied with one answer, therefore I believe it should be mentioned here.
Basically it was link to [this article.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Dynamic_Crystal_Report.aspx)

Cheers!